# Exchanging a code for a token in OpenID Connect authorization code flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect

The [OpenID Connect Basic Client Implementer's Guide](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html) claims in section [2.1.6.1](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#TokenRequest) that the client must send a `POST` request to the identity provider's `/token` route in order to exchange the authorization code for a token.

The sample shown there looks like this:

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA
  &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Fcb
```

I perfectly understand why one needs to provide the `grant_type` parameter, and I also understand why you need to provide the `code`.

But I take a look at section [2.1.6.2](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#TokenOK) the answer is not given by using a redirect, but by sending a simple `200` response with a JSON-encoded body:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache

{
  "access_token":"SlAV32hkKG",
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
  "id_token":"eyJ0 ... NiJ9.eyJ1c ... I6IjIifX0.DeWt4Qu ... ZXso"
}
```

No I wonder, if the response is *not* given using a redirect, but is directly sent to the client, then why does the request above contain a `redirect_uri` parameter?

Is this a copy/paste error from section [2.1.2](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#CodeRequest) where the authorization code is requested initially, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No I wonder, if the response is not given using a redirect, but is directly sent to the client, then why does the request above contain a redirect_uri parameter?

Sending the `redirect_uri` to the token endpoint is actually a security feature, well explained in the [`OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework` specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.6):

> When requesting authorization using the authorization code grant type, the client can specify a redirection URI via the "redirect_uri" parameter. If an attacker can manipulate the value of the redirection URI, it can cause the authorization server to redirect the resource owner user-agent to a URI under the control of the attacker with the authorization code.
>
> An attacker can create an account at a legitimate client and initiate the authorization flow.  When the attacker's user-agent is sent to the authorization server to grant access, the attacker grabs the authorization URI provided by the legitimate client and replaces the client's redirection URI with a URI under the control of the attacker. The attacker then tricks the victim into following the manipulated link to authorize access to the legitimate client.
>
> Once at the authorization server, the victim is prompted with a normal, valid request on behalf of a legitimate and trusted client, and authorizes the request.  The victim is then redirected to an endpoint under the control of the attacker with the authorization code.  The attacker completes the authorization flow by sending the authorization code to the client using the original redirection URI provided by the client.  The client exchanges the authorization code with an access token and links it to the attacker's client account, which can now gain access to the protected resources authorized by the victim (via the client).
>
> In order to prevent such an attack, the authorization server MUST ensure that the redirection URI used to obtain the authorization code is identical to the redirection URI provided when exchanging the authorization code for an access token. The authorization server MUST require public clients and SHOULD require confidential clients to register their redirection URIs. If a redirection URI is provided in the request, the authorization server MUST validate it against the registered value.

It's also mentioned in the [`OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations` RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.2.4.5):

> The authorization server should be able to bind every authorization "code" to the actual redirect URI used as the redirect target of the client in the end-user authorization process. This binding should be validated when the client attempts to exchange the respective authorization "code" for an access token. This measure is a countermeasure against authorization "code" leakage through counterfeit web sites, since an attacker cannot use another redirect URI to exchange an authorization "code" into a token.

Comment: I *almost* got it ;-). Just one thing left: Why can't "an attacker […] use another redirect URI to exchange an authorization "code" into a token."? Of course, it's obvious that it must match, so it can't be *another* one, but if the attacker is able to get the code, wouldn't they be able to get the redirect uri as well? AFAICS the redirect uri is not being used for an actual redirect, only for comparing, is it?

Comment: True. It's only used for comparing the `redirect_uri` with the `redirect_uri` originally sent by the client application. In practice, it's only useful in very specific scenarios, as the `client_id` comparison already prevents confused deputy attacks (where a client application would be given an authorization code issued to another client). Typical uses cases include applications that share the same `client_id` but have different `redirect_uri`, that point to different sections of the application. Comparing the `redirect_uri` ensures the code is exchanged by the right component of your app.

Comment: Another (theoretical) use case is when the authorization server allows client applications to register without having to list the `redirect_uri` they will use. In this case, this countermeasure is extremely important, as the authorization server can't detect that an attacker is trying to force a victim to be redirected to a fake `redirect_uri` during the authorization request (since the server can't compare it to a list of known URLs). In practice, this attack is extremely rare, as most authorization servers require registering a `redirect_uri` when creating the client application.

Comment: If you want to go deeper, I updated my answer to include the additional details mentioned by the OAuth2 specification, that clearly describes how this attack works. It's worth noting this attack is not applicable in the OpenID Connect world, as the specification is way stricter and explicitly says that the `redirect_uri MUST exactly match one of the Redirection URI values for the Client pre-registered at the OpenID Provider`.